How to display a list of lists as a matrix of "lists"?
Given a list of lists
listoflists = {{{a, b}, {1, 2}}, {{c, d}, {3, 4}}}

I would like to display it as a matrix of "lists".
Not as MatrixForm does it, that is as a 2x2 matrix of column vectors,
but as a 2x2 matrix of lists.
To my surprise
MatrixForm[{{"{a,b}", {1, 2}}, {{c, d}, {3, 4}}}]

Does display what I want but then a and b are no longer assignable as variables.

Maybe as follows: MatrixForm[listoflists, TableDepth -> 2].

@E.Chan-López Excellent, thank you.

As this might be useful for other users, let’s clarify this matter a bit. MatrixForm takes the depth of the array's rank by default, which is why MatrixForm[listoflists] appears by default as a matrix of column vectors and not as a matrix of lists. However, if we set TableDepth to a value less than the array's rank, in this case, 2, we get the desired result.
listoflists // TensorRank

(*3*)

MatrixForm[listoflists]

MatrixForm[listoflists, TableDepth -> 2]



